# C# Multithreading and WPF Page Control

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am a beginner on C#. There is a project I am working on need to use 2 threads. The main one is for displaying the usual Wpf pages. Another one monitoring the inputs from hardware. If there is a desired input signal detected, the whole system should stop and shows a warning page on the window, which is controlled by the main thread.

Now I get stuck on how to do the deal with the threads when the input signal detected. Should I pass a signal to the main thread, and ask the main thread to display the warning page, and stop the secondary thread. Or I should let the secondary thread display the warning page directly, and take over the control priority from the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF, like most GUI toolkits on Windows at least, has sticky controls - which essentially means they have thread affinity and cannot be accessed from other thread which didn't create them. [You can verify that from source, there are calls to `VerifyAccess()` littered all over the place.]

That design constraint rules out the possibility of other thread "taking over" anything from another thread, ever.

But the world doesn't end there, and cross-thread communication is common enough requirement that the designers have provided you with the means to satisfy the same thread requirements yet send messages across threads.

The way to do that lies with two members of Dispatcher object each WPF window has. You can read the full details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess?view=netcore-3.1) and on associated pages for that type, but roughly it goes like

```
 protected void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args) =>
     Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { /* Your method body which will be executed on the proper thread. */ });
```

If you prefer asynchronous communication, you can use either `BeginInvoke` or `InvokeAsync` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Or I should let the secondary thread display the warning page directly, and take over the control from the main thread?

That makes literally no sense at all.

> Should I stop the secondary thread and pass a signal to the main thread, and ask the main thread to display the warning page.

That also makes no sense at all, but at least there's a gleam of sort of what you mean here. To be absolutely clear, there's no such thing as "stopping threads" as you mean.

But yes, you send a message to the GUI thread to update its state, specifically using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` in WPF.

Comment: I was thinking to pass the signal to the main thread, and let the secondary one dies, then the main one do the remaining work.

Comment: Then you wrote your question wrong, because, as I quoted, you said you want to kill your thread first and then ask the main thread to do something.

Comment: Oh, yes. I didn't notice that. Sorry for the confusion.